# Background-color, svg and png in iOS

Tags: ios, css, svg, background, png

I have a svg background with a fallback png for devices that do not support svg. I try to give a background color too. It works in all desktop browsers, even IE8. But not in iOS. (I do not have any Android now to check)

In iOS. it works with svg, png or png and background-color or svg and background color. But it does not work with the 3 together.

So the question is, how to have all this together:
- iOS (and Android)
- background color
- svg
- png fallback

Please check your answer here: http://jsfiddle.net/TtWhH/
(I just use an img that could be in a public url, as example)

HTML:

```
<div id="grafic"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#grafic{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:512px; height:512px;
    max-width:980px;
    background-color:yellow;

    background-image:url('http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge.svg');
    background-image:none,url('http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge.svg'), url('http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge_512.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left top;       
}
```